# How to use unofficial features in Facebook group post editor?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, formatting, markdown

Recently formatted text cannot be pasted into Facebook group post editor. It will be converted to plain text. This is inconvenient if you have a well formatted text, and now have to reformat it again. Moreover, there are features that don't seem to be officially supported, but still be viable via pasting formatted text, like hyperlinks (not just plain URL).

[image]

Is there a way to use those unofficial features? I see the editor actually uses markdown on the beneath. Is there a way to use it?